# How to Copy Millions of Files from Remote Server to Local One

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, command-line, cpio

I have this problem, I have an Ubuntu server (SSH enabled on port `4444`). Inside this server there's a directory called `/folder/a/`, this directory **literally** contains millions of small size text files.

What i want to do is to find **several** thousands of files from those millions of files and copy or transfer those files to my local pc, i.e. using `find` command. When using `scp` or `cpio` it won't work properly.

Do you have any suggestion how to do this from my local pc, i.e **not** from running ssh terminal on my remote server.

Comment: It's possible to run `ssh` on the local PC with a command which is executed on the remote PC, and whose output is redirected back to the local PC. You can use this technique to execute `find` to build a list of files which is fed into `tar`. The output of `tar` is directed to the standard output of the `ssh` command. Note that the finding and archiving happens on the remove (server) PC. If that's not an option, you'd have to mount the remote directory into your local PC, which you can do with a network filesystem such as NFS, or even with SSH itself.

Comment: i know but, i want to do something like this (from local pc) `ssh -p 4444 username@11.11.11.11 "cd /folder && find ./a/ -xdev -name 'X*.somename.*' -mtime +0 -mtime -7 -print | head -15000"` but the problem is i dont know how to pipe or combine those `find` command with `scp` or `rsync` or even `tar` then transfer it to my local pc directory

Answer (score 2):

```
rsync -e 'ssh -p 4444' -a --include="pattern you want" --exclude="*" $S:/folder/a ~/copy
```

Or

```
ssh -p 4444 $S "find /folder/a -name 'pattern you want' | tar -cO -T -" > ~/copy.tar
```

Or

```
rsync -e 'ssh -p 4444' -a --files-from=<(ssh -p 444 $S find /folder/a -name 'pattern you want') $S:/folder/a ~/copy
```

Comment: thanks, how to combine `rsync` command with `find` command, since i want to use `find` with many of its options?

Comment: @xcode added to answer